# How does Magento's RDBMS-agnostic syntax handle date functions?

Tags: sql, magento, datetime, abstraction

I'm working on an extension intended for Magento 1.6 and above, and would like to use the general database syntax instead of the MySQL-specific one. I need a simple table to store a timestamp that I can use to select a set of orders.

I've looked through lib/Varien/Db and lib/Zend/Db, and the only date functions I see appear to be MySQL-specific:

```
lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Mysqli.php:    public function convertDate($date)
lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php: public function convertDate($date)
```

In MySQL I would write:

```
INSERT INTO `marketing_services` SET `last_sent` = NOW();
```

I know the major RDBMS systems differ in their vocabularies and implementations for date functions, but does Magento have an abstraction for this and other date functions, and if not, how should I go about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
/** @var $adapter Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface **/    
$now = $adapter->formatDate(Varien_Date::now())
// or
$nowDateOnlyWithoutTime = $adapter->formatDate(Varien_Date::now(), false)
```

Comment: This looks useful. It's just using PHP functions to format the date into a standard SQL date format, right?

Comment: Oh, wait a second, can't `$adapter->formatDate` just become the static `Varien_Date::formatDate`? That way I don't have to instantiate anything.

Comment: I recommend using the adapter, some RDBMS might need that. Probably not, but cleaner. Also, resource adapter always already is instantiated ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is Zend Framework code, nothing special in Magento with MySql.
[Source Code](https://github.com/breerly/zf1/blob/master/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php)

Insert:

```
$adapter->insert('marketing_services', array('last_sent'=>new Zend_Db_Expr('NOW()'));
```

Update:

```
$adapter->update('marketing_services', array('last_sent'=>new Zend_Db_Expr('NOW()'));
```

Comment: That's very helpful, but is there an abstraction that removes the need to call sql functions directly? (Since `NOW()` doesn't exist in TransactSQL, for example.)